# Proof regarding an alternating function?

Tags: calculus

so I'm in my first year studying maths at the University of Toronto and I saw this problem on the qualifying quiz for a math camp that my girlfriend's sister got and one of the questions stumped me. The problem pretty much boil down to this.

The function $f$ is describing the value of a collection of coins at the end of time $t$

$f(1)=1$, $f(2)=1+\phi$, $f(3)=2+\phi$, $f(4)=3+2\phi$

The question is to prove that $f(n)=\phi^n$.

I called it an alternating function because I honestly didn't know what else to call it as it seems like the function just alternates increasing the coefficient of one variable with each increase of t (sorry for the vaguery in asking the question)

This question stumped me and I'm actually doing pretty we in school so if anyone could help me out, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: By phi here, do you mean the golden ratio $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Comment: But then $ϕ^1=ϕ$, $ϕ^2=1+ϕ$, $ϕ^3=1+2ϕ$, $ϕ^4=2+3ϕ$.

Answer (score 1):

Really is this everything what the question give you? The unique pattern I see in this function is a "Fibonacci's sequence". Notice just the free number:
(1,1,2,3,...)
Now, look at the $\phi$ coefficient:
(0,1,1,2,....)

The first sequence seems like the Fibonacci's properly, while the second seems what we adding to the term to get the next, (what is the Fibonacci's sequence starting from 0).

Trying to proof that by induction I couldn't get the expression $\phi^{n}$... There is a free term, it can't vanish just because I want so... Isn't missing any information?

Comment: You can not prove it because it is not true. It is true only if $n=1$

Comment: Yeah, through the Given data your answer is the right, but she said that's a test question...this made me think is missing something.

Comment: This is the full question:

Comment: I have condensed the question due to the character limit.

You are working as an alchemist. Each silver piece is worth 1 dollar and each $\phi$ (golden ratio). You start with a single piece of silver and at the end of each day you turn each silver piece into a gold piece and then each gold piece into two silver pieces. At the end of day 1 you have 1 gold piece, at the end of day 2 you have 1 gold piece and 1 silver piece, at the end of day 3 you have 2 gold pieces and 1 silver piece. prove that at the end of day n, the treasure is worth $\phi^n$ dollars $\forall n>0$

Comment: "You start with a single piece of silver and at the end of each day you turn each silver piece into a gold piece and then [the following day?] each gold piece into two silver pieces."  If we can do both conversions the same day, then the first day should end with two silver pieces, but then you say we have one gold instead.  Odd.  Suppose we end the first day with one gold, then we split it into two silver -- we have presumably only enough capacity in our alchemical factory to convert one of them to gold, hence the one gold piece and one silver piece.

Comment: The next day, day 3, we presumably take the other silver piece and convert it to gold, while the gold piece we had turns into two silver pieces, except that's not what were told we have:  instead of one gold, two silver, we have two gold, one silver.  Odd. Conclusion:  the issue here is not math but examsmanship, i.e., the interpretation of questions.